# VB SCRIPT The system can not find the file specified ON SOME COMPUTERS/USERS

Tags: vbscript

Good day! I have this script that opens up an access application.

This script works on several users but one. This user is getting this error

> "Error 80070002: The system can not find the file specified".

I'm quite sure there is nothing wrong with my script as only one person is encountering this issue.

Could there be a computer setting or update that is causing this problem?
Everything works except for the Open File part.

And this is for some computers/user only. Most of the Computer/users can execute this without any problem.

Thanks in advance!

Here's the script

```
'*******************************************************************************
'Find user name
'*******************************************************************************    
Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
userName = WshNetwork.UserName
Set WshNetwork = Nothing

'******************************************************************************* 
'Find version of master file
'******************************************************************************* 
Set folder = objfso.GetFolder(folderPath)  
For Each file In folder.Files
    If InStr(file.Name, "AMSDshbd_M") = 1 Then
        masterVersion = Mid(file.Name, 11, (InStrRev(file.Name, ".") - 11))
        Exit For
    End If
Next

'*******************************************************************************
'Find version of user file, if it exists
'*******************************************************************************    
isUserFile = 0
For each file In folder.Files    
    If InStr(file.Name, "AMSDshbd_" & userName) = 1 Then
        isUserFile = 1
        userVersion = Mid(file.Name, (Len(userName) + 10), (InStrRev(file.Name, ".") - (Len(userName) + 10)))
        Exit For
    End If
Next

'*******************************************************************************
'Copy the file if no user file exists or if the user version is not current
'*******************************************************************************
sourceFile = folderPath & "AMSDshbd_M" & masterVersion & ".accde"
targetFile = folderPath & "AMSDshbd_" & userName & "_M" & masterVersion & ".accde"

isCopyNeeded = 1
if isUserFile = 1 then
    if userVersion = masterVersion then
        isCopyNeeded = 0
    end if
end if

if isCopyNeeded = 1 then
    objFSO.CopyFile sourceFile, targetFile, True
end if

'*******************************************************************************
'Open the file
'*******************************************************************************
sComTxt = Chr(34) & microsoftAccessFile & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & targetFile & Chr(34) 
'objShell.Run sComTxt
objShell.Run sComTxt,,true

Set objFSO = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Comment: What is `microsoftAccessFile`? Put `Option Explicit` at the top.

Comment: At which line does the error occur?

Comment: @HelO'Ween it's on "objShell.Run sComTxt,,true" error says line 86, that is where it points to.

Comment: @omegastripes it is declared as the Access Application itself, sorry I did not include the script. This is the script before "Find user name":

Comment: Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'microsoftAccessFile = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE"
'microsoftAccessFile = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE"
'microsoftAccessFile = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE'"

Comment: @omegastripes The option explicit doesn't work.... I am thinking maybe there is something on these particular users' computer

Comment: @Mackbear Please edit the question and move the code from comment to the question. What does it mean "The option explicit doesn't work"?

Comment: Add the line `WScript.Echo sComTxt` before the line `objShell.Run sComTxt,,true` and see if that variable has the desired value. I suspect that the creation of the file name(s) fails and with that you should be able to see what's wrong/missing.

Comment: Hi all, I figured out what happened. the variable "microsoftAccessFile" is the path to the MS Access EXE, some of the users have a different path to this Access EXE that's why it doesn't work for them. I identified the path where their Access EXE is stored and changed the script for them and it works now. Thanks for pointing out the variable @HelO'Ween

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what happened. the variable "microsoftAccessFile" is the path to the MS Access EXE, some of the users have a different path to this Access EXE that's why it doesn't work for them. I identified the path where their Access EXE is stored and changed the script for them and it works now. Thanks for pointing out the variable